# Aggregate results based on different fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get the count of location wise data and budget wise data in a single query for all owners from the same collection. In future we may need to show reports based on project wise as well.
Below is the sample collection.

```
[
  {
    "owner": 1,
    "location": "Goa",
    "budget": "1 Cr and Above",
    "project": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "owner": 1,
    "location": "Goa",
    "budget": "10 - 30 Lacs",
    "project": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "owner": 1,
    "location": "Mumbai",
    "budget": "30 - 50 Lacs",
    "project": "XYZ"
  },
  {
    "owner": 2,
    "location": "Delhi",
    "budget": "30 - 50 Lacs",
    "project": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "owner": 2,
    "location": "Delhi",
    "budget": "1 Cr and Above",
    "project": "DEF"
  },
  {
    "owner": 2,
    "location": "Delhi",
    "budget": "30 - 50 Lacs",
    "project": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "owner": 3,
    "location": "Goa",
    "budget": "70 - 90 Lacs",
    "project": "DEF"
  },
  {
    "owner": 3,
    "location": "Mumbai",
    "budget": "70 - 90 Lacs",
    "project": "XYZ"
  },
  {
    "owner": 4,
    "location": "Bangalore",
    "budget": "2 Cr and Above",
    "project": "DEF"
  },
  {
    "owner": 4,
    "location": "Goa",
    "budget": "2 Cr and Above",
    "project": "ABC"
  }
]
```

Below is the query I am executing to get location wise record for a owner:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "owner": "$owner",
        "location": "$location",
        "budget": "$budget"
      },
      "num": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.owner",
      "location": {
        "$push": {
          "location": "$_id.location",
          "count": "$num"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "owner": "$_id",
      "_id": false,
      "location": 1,
      "totalLocation": {
        "$sum": "$location.count"
      },
      "totalBudget": {
        "$sum": "$budget.count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The output is like below.

```
[
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Goa"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Bangalore"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 4,
    "totalLocation": 2
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 3,
        "location": "Delhi"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 2,
    "totalLocation": 3
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Mumbai"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "location": "Goa"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 1,
    "totalLocation": 3
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Goa"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Mumbai"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 3,
    "totalLocation": 2
  }
]
```

How shall I modify the same query to get the budget wise data also in the same result set ? Something like below.

```
[
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Goa"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Bangalore"
      }
    ],
    "budget": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "budget": "2 Cr and Above"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 4,
    "totalLocation": 2,
    "totalBudget": 2,
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 3,
        "location": "Delhi"
      }
    ],
    "budget": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "budget": "30 - 50 Lacs"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "budget": "1 Cr and Above"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 2,
    "totalLocation": 3,
    "totalBudget": 2
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Mumbai"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "location": "Goa"
      }
    ],
    "budget": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "budget": "1 Cr and Above"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "budget": "10 - 30 Lacs"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "budget": "30 - 50 Lacs"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 1,
    "totalLocation": 3,
    "totalBudget": 3
  },
  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Goa"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Mumbai"
      }
    ],
    "budget": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "budget": "70 - 90 Lacs"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 3,
    "totalLocation": 2,
    "totalBudget": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: If you take into consideration the option of different currencies, you need something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-MtnfS3rzRE , since the budget field contains both amount and currency together. Please note I changed the currency of one document to demonstrate it.

Comment: @nimrodserok Thanks for your inputs. This is mostly in sync with the output we need. Have edited the desired results, Can you please help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

In this case, I would edit my original response and suggest:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      budgets: [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "owner": "$owner",
              "budget": "$budget"
            },
            budgetCount: {$sum: 1}
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {"owner": "$_id.owner"},
            budgets: {
              "$addToSet": {
                budget: "$_id.budget",
                count: "$budgetCount"
              }
            },
            totalBudgets: {$sum: "$budgetCount"},
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            owner: "$_id.owner",
            _id: 0,
            budgets: 1,
            totalBudgets: 1,
            locations: null,
            projects: null
          }
        }
      ],
      locations: [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "owner": "$owner",
              "location": "$location"
            },
            locationsCount: {$sum: 1}
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {"owner": "$_id.owner"},
            locations: {
              "$addToSet": {
                location: "$_id.location",
                count: "$budgetCount"
              }
            },
            totalLocations: {$sum: "$locationsCount"},
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            owner: "$_id.owner",
            _id: 0,
            locations: 1,
            totalLocations: 1,
            budgets: null,
            projects: null
          }
        }
      ],
      projects: [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "owner": "$owner",
              "project": "$project"
            },
            projectsCount: {$sum: 1}
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {"owner": "$_id.owner"},
            projects: {
              "$addToSet": {
                project: "$_id.project",
                count: "$projectsCount"
              }
            },
            totalProjects: {$sum: "$projectsCount"},
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            owner: "$_id.owner",
            _id: 0,
            projects: 1,
            totalProjects: 1,
            budgets: null,
            locations: null
          }
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$budgets",
          "$locations",
          "$projects"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$data.owner",
      locations: {
        $push: {
          $ifNull: ["$data.locations", "$$REMOVE"]
        }
      },
      budgets: {
        $push: {
          $ifNull: ["$data.budgets", "$$REMOVE"]
        }
      },
      projects: {
        $push: {
          $ifNull: ["$data.projects", "$$REMOVE"]
        }
      },
      totalBudgets: {$sum: "$data.totalBudgets"},
      totalLocations: {$sum: "$data.totalLocations"},
      totalProjects: {$sum: "$data.totalProjects"},   
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "owner": "$_id",
      "locations": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$locations", 0]},
      "projects": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$projects", 0]},
      "budget": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$budgets", 0]},
      totalBudgets: 1,
      totalLocations: 1,
      totalProjects: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Which you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lPD8wilpI5D) with small changes in the input data, in order to demonstrate the functionality.

Comment: This is good. Just a small error i think, the total budget count is not coming as sum of budget, it is coming as the number of unique budget count. ex- {
    "budget": [
      {
        "budget": "2 Cr and Above",
        "count": 2
      }
    ],
    "locations": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Bangalore"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "location": "Goa"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 4,
    "totalBudget": 1,
    "totalLocations": 2
  }.

Here totalBudget should be 2 not 1. Rest all is perfectly fine.

Comment: also in future if we wish to add projects also in the result set what do we have to do ?

Comment: Because this is the case in your example of wanted results:  {
    "location": [
      {
        "count": 3,
        "location": "Delhi"
      }
    ],
    "budget": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "budget": "30 - 50 Lacs"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "budget": "1 Cr and Above"
      }
    ],
    "owner": 2,
    "totalLocation": 3,
    "totalBudget": 2
  },  otherwise the budget count is the same as location count - can be fixed easily on the last `$project`. Are you sure you want them to be the same?

Comment: Regarding the project, it depends on the wanted outcome

Comment: Yes the total count will be same as of location and the wanted outcome for projects also will be similar to budget and location. ex- for Owner 4,
 {"budget": [{
 "budget": "2 Cr and Above",
 "count": 2
  }],
"locations": [{
 "count": 1,
 "location": "Goa"
  },
  {
 "count": 1,
 "location": "Bangalore"
  }],
"projects": [{
 "count": 1,
 "project": "ABC"
  },
  {
 "count": 1,
 "project": "DEF"
  }],
"owner": 4,
"totalBudget": 2,
"totalLocations": 2,
"totalProjects": 2}

Comment: Please check the suggested answer now, after I edited it